# Why would I use a thermistor instead of a LM35/36?

Tags: sensor, temperature

Is there any advantage over the other in using a thermistor versus a temp sensor like a LM36 or LM35?

The only major difference I can see is that the LM35/36 have voltage limits of 5.5V and the thermistor is more of a really temp sensitive resistor that I could use with any voltage I want.  Maybe the temp ranges?

Is that about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thermistors are cheaper and smaller which is useful for applications where many points have to be sensed and little room is available.  They can cover a wider temperature range than the LM35.  They only have 2 leads and require less power per sensor since many sensors can share a readout circuit.  They can also provide higher accuracy if needed.  For example there are oceanographic thermistors deigned just for measuring the temperature of seawater that are accurate to less than 0.1 C degree over the -5C to 35C range. They are useful in circuits where a temperature variable resistor is needed instead of a voltage proportional to temperature.

Answer (score 6):

We use thermistors over those types of chips due to accuracy requirements.

For example [this](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/TMP35_36_37.pdf) analog devices TMP35/36/37 datasheet has an accuracy of +-1 degree Celcius, whereas a thermistor like [this](http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=3108&la_id=1&pr_id=53879) has +-0.2 degrees tolerance (@25degC).